# Why is exponentiation applied right to left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, exponentiation

I am reading an Intro to Python textbook and came across this line:

> Operators on the same row have equal precedence and are applied left to right, except for exponentiation, which is applied right to left.

I understand most of this, but I do not understand why they say exponentiation is applied right to left. They do not provide any examples either. Also, am I allowed to ask general questions like this, or are only problem solving questions preferred?

Comment: That wording is slightly confusing. It is talking about binding behaviour, meaning that in a *larger expression*, determining what values the `**` binds to is determined by the precedence order. So in `a + b ** c ** d`, what is executed first is determined by the precedence order.

Comment: And the order follows maths conventions, just like multiplication being applied before addition.

Comment: In the example a + b ** c * d, I guess it would then be (c * d) ** (a + b), correct? Because according to precedence order multiplication applies before addition.

Comment: `**` binds more tightly than multiplication or addition. So it is `c * (d ** a) + b`.

Comment: shouldn't... a + b ** c ** d ...be... a + (b ** (c ** d)) ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `**` operator follows [normal mathematical conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633790/what-is-the-order-when-doing-xyz-and-why); it is right-associative:

> In the usual computer science jargon, exponentiation in mathematics is right-associative, which means that x<sup>y<sup>z</sup></sup> should be read as x<sup>(y<sup>z</sup>)</sup>, not (x<sup>y</sup>)<sup>z</sup>. In expositions of the BODMAS rules that are careful enough to address this question, the rule is to evaluate the top exponent first.

and from [Wikipedia on the *Order of Operations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Special_cases):

> If exponentiation is indicated by stacked symbols, the usual rule is to work from the top down, because exponention is right-associative in mathematics.

So `2 ** 3 ** 4` is calculated as `2 ** (3 ** 4)` (== 2417851639229258349412352) not `(2 ** 3) ** 4` (== 4096).

This is pretty universal across programming languages; it is called *right-associativity*, although there *are* exceptions, with Excel and MATLAB being the most notable.

Comment: Hi Martijn. I have one more question. Could you please explain to me why you chose the expression a + b ** c * d as an example in the first place? The only reason I am asking is because it only has one exponent in the expression. Thanks~

Comment: @elitecheese1337: it was a dumb example, one that doesn't illustrate the issue. Sorry. :-/

Comment: @elitecheese1337: it should have been `a + b ** c ** d`, really.

Comment: There are many exceptions. Here is a large list of how different languages and apps handle exponential operator: https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options

Answer (score 2):

from http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html

Operators in the same box group left to right (except for comparisons, including tests, which all have the same precedence and chain from left to right — see section Comparisons — and exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

```
>>> 2 ** 2 ** 2
16
>>> 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2
65536
>>> (2 ** 2 ** 2) ** 2
256
```

For the middle case `2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2`, this are the intermediate steps -

1. broken down to `2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 2))`
2. `2 ** (2 ** (4)) # progressing right to left`
3. `2 ** (16) # this is 2 to the power 16`
   which finally evals to `65536`
   Hope that helps!

Comment: I just wanted to list out an example which goes from expected to unexpected behaviour and then explains what's up... but what you're saying makes sense

Answer (score 2):

This explanation seems quite clear to me. Let me show you an example that might enlighten this :

`print 2 ** 2 ** 3 # prints 256`

If you would read this from left to right, you would first do `2 ** 2`, which would result in 4, and then `4 ** 3`, which would give us 64.
It seems we have a wrong answer. :)

However, from right to left...
You would first do `2 ** 3`, which would be 8, and then, `2 ** 8`, giving us 256 !

I hope I was able to enlighten this point for you. :)

EDIT : Martijn Pieters answered more accurately to your question, sorry. I forgot to say it was mathematical conventions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense to me! Originally what I was thinking is that they meant 3 ** 2 ** 2 when they said right to left. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Power operator, exponentiation, is handled differently across applications and languages.

If it has LEFT associativity then 2^3^4 = (2^3)^4 = 4096.
If it has RIGHT associativity then 2^3^4 = 2^(3^4) = 2417851639229260000000000.

In Excel, Matlab, Apple Numbers and more others exponentiation has LEFT associativity.
In Python, Ruby, Google Sheets, ... - RIGHT associativity.

Here is a vast list of how different languages and apps handle exponentiation: [Exponentiation Associativity and Standard Math Notation](https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options)