# Order of calculation

Tags: python

Example : 10 ** 4*3 ** 2

Our teacher said python first calculates `3**2` and then `10**4` and then multiplies the answers.

But if both side of the multiplication have same order of precedence and python reads from left to right, doesn’t it do `10**4` first and then `3**2`?

(My question is not about the order or precedence of operations as both side have same order of precedence)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is exponentiation applied right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left)

Comment: @gst It really does not look like a duplicate

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  The linked question above pertains to the associativity of exponentiation.  The OP is correct, the teacher is wrong, though for pure calculations of equal precedence, the order doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @ChatterOne i think gst is right, the question is regarding the precedence and the duplicate answer is providing correct solution

Comment: @prashantrana No, the linked question is about exponentiation only and its associativity. This one is about precedence between two different operations.

Comment: @ChuckAdams in actual mathematics order not matter , but in programming how a langauge do these calculation and process data , order matters

Comment: I think right-associativity discussed and linked in the alleged duplicate still applies and thus answers the question.

Comment: @gst first, it has nothing to do with associativity, second, the teacher's claim is wrong, so it can't be a duplicate.

Comment: @gst Associativity explains why `2**3**4 == 2**(3**4)`; precedence explains why `10**4*3**2 == (10**4)*(3**2)`.

Comment: I see that I was wrong in saying it's dupe but I don't think that `10**4*3**2 == (10**4)*(3**2)` was ever in question. It was hard for me to see how (using hard-coded numbers) the real question would be relevant so I misinterpreted it.

Comment: It's not; my point was just to demonstrate that associativity was never a relevant concept for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is wrong. From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order:

> ## 6.15. Evaluation order
>
> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while
> evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the
> left-hand side.

The `*` has two expressions as its operands, `10**4` and `3**2`. The left operand, `10**4` is evaluated first, followed by the right operand, `3**2`.

Your teacher may be confused with a *chain* of exponentiations like `2 ** 3 ** 4`. Here the "outer" exponentiation has two arguments `2` and `3 ** 4` (rather than `2**3` and `4`, because of right associativity). However, the `2` is still evaluated before `3**4`.

For a simple expression like this, it doesn't really matter. But it *could* matter if one or both operands involved function calls with side effects. Consider something contrived like `lambda: print(3) or 3)() + (lambda: print(4) or 4)()`. The value of the expression is 7 either way, but the order in which the `print` functions are called will affect the output. Python, though, guarantees that `3` will be output before `4`.

---

Some languages (notably C, IIRC) don't specify an order of evaluation, so it is an implementation detail whether the left or right is evaluated first. This means you can't predict the value of something like `i=3; j=(i++)*i`; `j` could be either `3*3 == 9` or `4*3 == 12`, depending on whether `i` is incremented before or after the right-hand operand is evaluated. (I don't recall if this is considered undefined behavior or implementation-defined behavior, though.)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can easily test it:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, v): 
        self.v = v 

    def __pow__(self, x): 
        print(f'eval {self.v} ** {x}') 
        return self.v ** x 

>>> C(1) ** 2 * C(4) ** 5
eval 1 ** 2
eval 4 ** 5
1024
```

In short, your teacher is wrong, at least for Python 3.7. In any case, regardless of whether it's true, I'd never rely on the order here, since those assumptions make the code less readable.

Comment: Damn, you beat me while I was typing :-)

Comment: This could just be revealing an implementation detail of (I assume) CPython. I don't  recall if the language itself specifies that the arguments of an operator are evaluated left to right. (I would be *extremely* surprised if, given the choice, an operator *would* bother to evaluate them right to left, though.)

Comment: @chepner The language does not specify right-to-left either, and this counter-example proves that at least claiming right-to-left is wrong.

Comment: Moot point: I found the reference for Python explicitly specifying left-to-right evaluation.