# Is Groovy Power Operator (**) Broken in Associativity?

Tags: groovy, exponentiation

In Groovy 3.0 (Groovy Version: 3.0.0-rc-1 JVM: 11.0.2)

```
println 3**3**3
println 3.0**3.0**3.0
```

gives

```
19683
19683
```

In Python (Python 3.5.2) from the terminal, I get

```
>>> 3**3**3
7625597484987
>>> (3**3)**3
19683
```

The [official site](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#power_operator) does not give any indication.

Is ** broken in Groovy as of now?

---

EDIT

Answers in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left), [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673740/why-is-exponentiation-right-associative) make it clear that the the mathematical convention is that exponentiation is right associative.

Defect is [defined](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/defect/) as a condition in a software product which does not meet a software requirement (as stated in the requirement specifications) or end-user expectation (which may not be specified but is reasonable).

Since this reasonable expectation is violated in an undocumented manner, is not this considered a bug?

Comment: This question will be even more useful if  you used same example from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Exponentiation_order (5,3,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not broken

It just has left to right associativity as with all other operators

In python `**` has right to left associativity, so that's not broken either

They just have different rules

Comment: Maths rules are often not transferred to computer languages (see bodmas).  Different languages treat infix operators like this differently, you just have to learn the rule for your language of interest https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Exponentiation_order