# roll dice in Python

Tags: python

I need to find expectation of the number of 100 times that I need to roll
a fair die until I get all six numbers

And here is my code. I don't know how to put it into while loop for 100 times. Can anyone help?

for example:
the first time I rolled to get all six numbers, I need to roll 8 times.
the second time I rolled to get all six numbers, I roll 13 times
Then I record as follows:
1: 8
2: 13
...
100:9

I want my a=[8,13,.....,9]

```
import random
trials = []
a=[]
collection = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(6)]
for c in collection:
    if c not in a:
        a.append(c)
    
    else:
        collection.append(random.randint(1,6))
trials.append(len(collection))

print(a)
print(collection)
print(trials)
```

Comment: do u have to roll the dice 100 times and store their numbers or roll the dice a max 100 times and stop once you get all 6 numbers? What's the question?

Comment: What things do you want to get? How long it takes - if you roll a random fair 1d6  - to get each number at least once? And capture how long it took?  Do you need the resultarrays of what was rolled until at least all 6 numbers are present?

Comment: Solution without using simulation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left, the answer is 14.7. Depending on how precise your want you want to be, 100 simulations may not be enough.

Comment: @LeonardusChen - what has operator precedence to do with this?

Comment: @PatrickArtner - turns out I wrote the wrong link - no idea why I did that. I wanted to link an analytical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo:

- create empty dict for results
- do 100 times

  - create set of numbers 1-6
  - create empty list of this tries drawn numbers
  - while there are still numbers in the set repeat:

    - draw a number and add it to your list
    - remove number from set if in it
  - add list to dict
- evaluate stuff

Or in code:

```
import random

results = {}

for t in range(100):
    nums = set((1,2,3,4,5,6))
    data = []
    # do as long as we still lack one number
    while nums:
        n = random.randint(1,6)
        data.append(n)
        # remove if in, else we dont care
        if n in nums:
            nums.remove(n)
    # add the list to your results - if you just need the lenghts don't
    # store the whole list here, just store its lenghts and adapt the 
    # evaluation code
    results[t] = data

# evaluation
lengths = [len(w) for w in results.values()]

average_lengths = sum(l for l in lengths) / 100
max_lengths = max(lengths)
min_lengths = min(lengths)

# output
print(min_lengths, average_lengths, max_lengths)
```

Output:

```
6 13.95 31
```

You can print the dictionary `results` to see all dices rolled.
You can print the list `lenghts` to see all 100 varying lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it like this:

```
import random
n = 1
trials = []
while n<=100:
    a=[]
    collection = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(6)]
    for c in collection:
        if c not in a:
            a.append(c)
        
        else:
            collection.append(random.randint(1,6))
    trials.append(len(collection))
    n += 1
    print(a)
    print(collection)
    print(trials)
```

Just do `n = 1` and `while n <= 100` and `n += 1`

And here is the average code:

```
import random
n = 1
trials = []
while n<=100:
    a=[]
    collection = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(6)]
    for c in collection:
        if c not in a:
            a.append(c)
        
        else:
            collection.append(random.randint(1,6))
    trials.append(len(collection))
    n += 1
    #print(a)
    #print(collection)
    #print(trials)
print(sum(trials) / len(trials))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `print(sum(trials) / len(trials))`?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work as wanted?:

```
from random import randint

trials = []
goal = set(list(range(1, 7)))
for _ in range(100):
    attempts = 0
    cur = set()
    while cur != goal:
        cur.add(randint(1, 6))
        attempts += 1
    trials.append(attempts)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the for loop in another loop:

```py
for i in range(100):
    a = []
    for c in coll:
        if c not in a:
            a.append(c)
        else:
            coll.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    trials.append(len(coll))
```

Comment: to begin with, it will never enter the loop. then for the next 98 times it will NOT and you will end up with an empty list. Isnt that what this code will do?