# Python exponential calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am New to python trying out some basic python function. Came across exponential
In python

2 ** 2 ** 3 is 256

But while in mathematics getting as 64.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left

Comment: I'm curious though, what's the rationale behind the decision to evaluate exponentiation from right to left? @WalterTross . Nevermind got my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left

Comment: @LeonardusChen I guess it's because you can live without `(a**b)**c`, because it's equal to `a**(b*c)`, but you cannot do anything similar with `a**(b**c)`

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses. This will give the correct answer.

```
(2 ** 2) ** 3
```

Comment: "correct"? "This will give the answer you expect", maybe

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses

```
x = (2**2)**3
```

or:

```
pow(2,2*3)
```