# In Python, why does exponentiation group from right to left?

Tags: python

For example, why is `2**3**2` equivalent to `2**9` instead of `8**2`?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence%5D) state:

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

, but why is exponentiation different from all the other operators?

Comment: at a guess, it'd be because the basic interpretation of "2^3^2" would be "2^(3^2)" (after all, if you wanted (2^3)^2 you could just do 2^(3*2)).

Comment: Answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left

Comment: @AmeshJayaweera Thanks! Interestingly, my Casio evaluates exponentiation from left to right.  I guess I just got used to that.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue because the `**` operator follows normal mathematical conventions. It is right associative.
Just like you would read this 2^3^2 as 2^(3^2) and not as (2^3)^2. Of course there are exceptions but I think this is pretty universal across programming languages.