# Calculation divergence in Python

Tags: python, math, excel-formula, calculation

I did this calculation in Python:

```
    ((1.00044*(1.00175/1.00044)**(252/(4-1))**((1-1)/252))**(252/1)-1)*100

    55.36617662154271
```

The same calculation in Excel presents this result: 11,7234.

What is the reason for this divergence?

Comment: I think you've probably made some typo's as the equation above simplifies to this: ```(1.00175**252-1)*100``` output: ```55.36617662154271```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Excel and Python, your expression can be reduced to:

```
((1.00044*(1.00175/1.00044)**84**0)**252-1)*100
```

The difference is how they evaluate power expressions (exponentiation). Python follows [mathematical conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429513/why-is-exponentiation-applied-right-to-left) in applying right-associative exponentiation. `2 ** 3 ** 4 == 2 ** (3 ** 4) == 2417851639229258349412352`. In Excel, exponentiation is left-to-right so `2 ^ 3 ^ 4` is evaluated as `(2 ^ 3) ^ 4 = 4096`.

If you add brackets to make Python evaluate the `**84` before the `**0` then you get the same result as in Excel:

```
((1.00044*((1.00175/1.00044)**84)**0)**252-1)*100   # 11.7234
```

Or if you add brackets in a different place you can get the Python result in Excel:

```
=((1.00044*(1.00175/1.00044)^(84^0))^252-1)*100   # 55.366
```

Comment: So I'm not adding typos, excel doesn't know how to evaluate equations